# Can't figure out what's wrong with data type in numpy loadtxt command

Tags: python, numpy, format

I'm trying to read in an Ascii file using loadtxt. The file looks like this

```
UT, L, R, LocT, MLT, MLAT
      240000      1.03033      1.06433      2.73627      2.93244      8.51725
      300000      1.01964      1.05914      3.07449      3.24764      6.54548
      360000      1.01194      1.05747      3.41200      3.56224      4.51283
      420000      1.00746      1.05935      3.74672      3.87489      2.44624
      480000      1.00702      1.06476      4.07669      4.18431     0.373423
```

However there can be at least 9 characters in any of the rows.

I've been using this code

```
posdata = np.loadtxt(denfile, dtype={'names':('UT', 'L', 'R', 'loct', 'MLT', 'Mlat'), 'formats':('I9', 'f9', 'f9', 'f9', 'f9', 'f9')} , skiprows = 1)
```

and I get an error which reads `TypeError: data type not understood`. When I use a lower case i I get the same error. However in the line above where I read in a different file if the i is lowercase it doesn't work, but if it's upper case it does.

I'm not sure where the error is occurring or how to fix it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would help if you could make a small snippet of the file available for download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a 72-bit float in numpy.

Either specify `'f8'`/`'I8'` or for easier readibility: `np.float`/`np.uint`.  There's no `'f9'` (which would be a 72-bit float).

Have a look at the documentation for [defining a dtype in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

For your case you probably don't need to bother with this, though.

If you don't really need things as a structured array, then don't use one. (If you don't know what a structured array is, you probably don't need it in this case.)

Just do `data = np.loadtxt("datafile.txt", skiprows=1)`.  If you do need a structured array, then consider doing `data = np.genfromtxt("datafile.txt", names=True)`.  For simple cases, it's easier to cast the first column as an unsigned integer later, rather than explicitly defining a dtype.

Comment: I guess then I'm confused by what the number after the f means. I thought it meant how many characters the number could be. I'm coming from an idl background where the format code would be (number of repeats)f(length of number). Just so I know in the future, how does python do this, or does it even care what the length of the number is? When I try 'f8' I get invalid literal for float(): VTCW. Thanks for your help

Comment: It has nothing to do with the length of a string.  It's the number of _bytes_ used to store an item in the array.  `'f8'` is a 64-bit (8 byte) float.  (`'<f8'` is a little-endian float and `'>f8'` is a big-endian float, if you need to specify endian-ness)  Generally speaking, it's best not to specify dtypes using those sorts of string shorthands.  Sometimes you need to, but it's more readable to do `np.float64` instead of `'f8'`.

Comment: You're getting the "invalid literal for float()" error because some line in your data has something that can't be converted to a floating point number (e.g. characters).  If you have missing data, then you'll need to deal with it explicitly.  (Have a look at `np.genfromtxt`.)

Comment: I'm still getting the error. There is no missing data and no letters would a minus sign do it or a tab instead of a space?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can you show the exact traceback and the code you're trying?

Comment: Okay I have egg on my face, wrong file name so you are right that there were strings in the floating point.Thanks for your help. Changing the f8 to np.float64 did do the trick.